# How can I duplicate categories and tags?

Tags: categories, tags

Is there a way to sync categories and tags? I want a way that every post will have a tag that is the same as the category or categories that its in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'add_tag_based_on_category' );

function add_tag_based_on_category( $post_id ) {
    $args = array( 'fields' => 'names' );
    $categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post_id, $args );
    $cat_names = implode( ', ', $categories );
    wp_set_post_tags( $post_id, $cat_names, true );
}
```

Comment: Nothing happened to existing posts, or to the new post I made with a category. I put it in the `functions.php` file, is that the wrong place?

Comment: Edited! I added 'name' instead 'names' at $args. For existing posts, just press the Update post button.

Comment: Is there any way to emulate pressing the update button on all posts?

Comment: [Snippet](https://gist.github.com/luancuba/b58b7ec8280a49cb1625c2d6114b8ac1), run it once.